# How to scan an image (from PC display) using Android phone camera and convert image data in OpenCV Mat format?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, scanning

I need to scan an image (or video stream) using a mobile camera on an Android device, and transform the resulting image into OpenCV Mat format.

Is there any library or OpenCV-android-sdk method to do this?

Comment: Hi. Are you asking for what ? Code ? Steps ? An article to achieve that ?

Comment: @Link yep, I need some code or helping libraries to do this stuff. (i will check to google vision library(barcode reader etc.) but I could not understand it suitable for my work.  so, need some expert guidance to do this. ?

Comment: I wrote a [tutorial on Github](https://github.com/VlSomers/native-opencv-android-template) with a sample OpenCV Android application. This sample application displays a live camera feed with an OpenCV adaptive threshold filter applied on each frame. The OpenCV adaptive threshold call is performed in C++. Hope it will help.

Comment: @vSomers thank you. I will refer it. :) but I need to know are there any different scan image trough  camera and just capturing image from camera  ?

Comment: @vSomers are there any way to convert your project java? I am not familiar that language /

Comment: @uma I'm going to write a Java version

Comment: @uma you can find the Java version [here](https://github.com/VlSomers/native-opencv-android-template/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/nativeopencvandroidtemplate/MainActivity.java)

Comment: @vSomers Thank lot of .., can  i used this as image scanner ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "image scanner"?

Comment: like we used camera as scan QR code , are there any different between that process ? (i need to know image capture and scan  both same or different) . I saw playstoer as some app to image scan.

Comment: @vSomers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58238681/are-there-any-different-between-scan-image-through-camera-and-capturing-image-fr  i post different  question also  ,but not yet any help.