# Are there any different between Scan image through camera and capturing image from camera?

Tags: android, opencv, barcode-scanner, scanning, image-scanner

I need to know that different between scanning and taking photo from camera . As example we normally , SCAN QR code , bar code , like thing using android phone.They are also image. we can take photo from camera. it also image.

So ,is it Scanning QR code , mean take image and processing  it or are there have any special thing  take image from pixel values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Biggest difference is that when you **capture** an image you get a processed jpg file, when you're **scanning** you're working with raw YUV byte array.

When talking about a **picture** you usually need to worry about quality, flash, aperture, shutter speed, iso, white balance and a lot of other things that will make it a good picture and nice for people to see, and when you're working with a **scan** you usually don't care much about any of these things, you just need to get information from the image.

Another big difference is that you can capture a lot of YUV bytes very fast, while taking a picture takes time.

That covers the basic differences, but there's a lot of info when talking about photo and scanning, and more when you enter a specific subject. I suggest you to read about [Camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera) and [Camera preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478375/how-can-i-manipulate-the-camera-preview).

Comment: Thank you , really i need to take stago(stenography)  image from camera and decode it. can you give me more detail related to it ?

Comment: It is thank for u can address , android related libraries or some source code to do this task.

Comment: I didn't understand it, isn't stenography about recording what someone is saying? How can that relate to images and camera? But in any case, I think [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit) is a good starting point, take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

The similarity between scanning and capturing is that data stored is in the form of image. However, there is a difference in quality of both the images. While capturing image from camera, you can vary the focus in order to get sharp image of 3D object. Beside that there are exposure controls within the camera which helps in this process. 
Scanning produces image taking line by line information. It works well for flat objects like papers and documents kept at very close distance. 
So, in your example of barcode, scanning and capturing image will use similar process but produce two different results in terms of quality.

Answer (score -2):

In order to get the value of an QR-Code in the real world, you need to first **capture** an image containing the QR-Code.

Once you have this image, you can **scan** it for the QR-Code and do some processing in order to decode it.

See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scan):

> (computing, transitive) To read with an electronic device.
>
> > to **scan** a barcode; to **scan** a QR code

In order to **scan** the QR-Code you need to **capture** the image and then process it.

Usually the **capturing** of the image is neglected, because it is a trivial step.

Comment: Can you be clear about what you want to say here about the question? Just repeating the same thing twice doesn't help